# Discord.py ERROR sending message to channel

Tags: python

```
 File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 101, in _loop
 await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
2022-09-09T20:52:06.079611+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/main.py", line 14, in test
2022-09-09T20:52:06.079612+00:00 app[worker.1]:     channel.send("test")
2022-09-09T20:52:06.079624+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I'm using `discord.py` and I keep getting that error

```
import discord
import os


from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='..')

@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def test():
 
    channel = client.get_channel(1017890755462824078)
    channel.send("test")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    test.start()
    print("test")


client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Comment: error suggests that it couldn't find channel `1017890755462824078` and you have `channel = None` and later `None.send(....)`. Maybe you should skip it `if channel is not None: channel.send(...)`. OR you should check in documentation if you need some special privileges to access this channel.